# How to deal with arbitrary sets of data in C

Tags: c, dataset, singleton

I'm currently learning to code (in C mainly, but other languages as well), and in several projects now I've been confronted with the same kind of "problem":

Often I have to deal with arbitrary sets of data. For example, I may need to write a program that will take a definite number of commands (let's say 11 for the sake of example) in its standard form, but I want to make a code that is flexible, so for example if I come back later on this project and want to add other commands, I want to be able to do so easily.

I need to manually input the names of these commands somewhere at some point in my code. A way I currently like is to use an array of structures, each element containing a char* for the name of the command and a function pointer for the function in charge of what the command does.

The problem is that as of yet, I haven't really implemented this array in a way that completely satisfies me.

The closest I got from it was through a singleton, every time I need the array I just call my singleton, but since then I've learned that singletons pose essentially the same kind of problems as global variables do. I've learned a bit about dependency injection but this is a principle which seems to only apply to Object Oriented languages.

Is there a way to not use singletons for what I want to do in C?

TL;DR:
I need to build arbitrary sets of data in my code, how can I implement this in an elegant and easily maintainable way?

Thanks for anyone who'll take the time to answer.

Example:

I have a program that listen to commands on the standard input and then execute these commands.
Every time I read an input, I compare it to a predetermined list of commands (in the form of strings), and then execute the appropriate code if a command matches.

How would you create the set of strings? How would you create the set of functions which correspond to each string? How would you link the two sets together? How would you make this combined set easily accessible anywhere?

So far my answer to this has been:

```
s_cmds *singleton(void)
{
    static s_cmds ret[] = {{"cmd1", &func_cmd1}, {"cmd2", &func_cmd2}, ...};
    return (ret);
}
```

with a structure:

```
struct s_cmds {
    char *cmd;
    void (*func_cmd)(...);
};
```

This way, regardless of how I want to make my code evolve, if I want to add a command, I just need to add an element in my singleton, and if I want to access this array somewhere else in my code, I just need to call the singleton. But this is essentially like using a global variable isn't it?

Is there a "cleaner" way to do it?

Comment: Could you rewrite this with a specific example? It's way to generic as it is written currently.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I added the example I'm currently working on. I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is very vague, but I think that you are looking for X-Macros:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro

It's a code construct used to bind together related code of different type. Common use case is handling of error codes and their text representation.

Comment: This is quite interesting and it may help me indeed, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your question but from the sound of it, I think you are looking for a data structure like a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). You can add elements i.e. your new commands to it much easier than whatever you would be doing with a regular array. Obviously there advantages or disadvantages, without other knowledge of your problem, it's hard to say what exactly you could use.

Comment: I've added an example, I hope it's a bit more precise. A linked list is problematic in the way that I really don't want to have to go through manually creating my 11 commands and allocating memory for this. I mean this content will never change once the program runs, I see no reason to use dynamic memory, right?

Comment: @Arjofocolovi Ok, the example made it much clearer. In your case, yes a linked list and dynamic memory is not needed. Now your solution is already neat as it is. Remember that there is nothing wrong with using a plain old global variable. In your case, a singleton is even going into overkill. If you want something globally visible, then make it gobally visible, overcomplicating with design patterns won't help. Alternatively, don't have globals in your code. Refactor with maybe a method that takes a command as a parameter and returns a function pointer to the correct command.

Comment: I understand. However, I'm not allowed to use global variables for this project (and it's generally advised against in my school). The argument is that it can create complications precisely because of the global scope, resulting in not knowing what parts of the code can read and edit these variables. So you personally think that you would have used a global variable in this example?

Comment: @Arjofocolovi Personally I would have a short method as I described that takes a string as a parameter, compares it to a list of available commands and then calls/returns function pointer to the correct one. How you do the comparison is up to you. That way you get rid of the global and singleton issue since the array now becomes private to that method and only updated from that method. Unless you have some sort of reason for keeping that array of yours global.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that my need for global access is probably the source of my problems in the end. I was ultimately looking for a way to have a global without having the cons of the global. I guess this is not really possible since the cons are probably linked to the nature of any global piece of code. I suppose I just need to manage local access correctly and use global ones only when really needed. Thanks for the help.